# i do not get the logic behind this code. Can someone please explain to me what it really does and how?

Tags: java

```
class Echo{
  
  int count = 0;
  
  void hello(){
    
    System.out.println("hellooo...");
    
  }
  
}


public class EchoTestDrive {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
     Echo e1 = new Echo();
     Echo e2 = new Echo();
     
     int x=0;
     
     while(x<4){
       
       e1.hello();
       e1.count = e1.count+1;
       
       if(x==3){
         
         e2.count = e2.count +1;
       }
       
       if (x>0){
         
         e2.count = e2.count + e1.count;
       }
       x=x+1;
     }
     System.out.println(e2.count);
  
   
  }
}
```

Comment: have you run at least this code?

Comment: so is some part of the code unclear to you?

Comment: Yes. It prints out : hellooo... 4 times in a new line and 10 at the end of a new line. I just don't understand how.

Comment: Yes, it prints hello because it's called in a loop 4 times. The 10 is the value in e2 printed after the loop.

Comment: What context did you see this code in? Was this something in use or was it a coding example?

Comment: It's a coding example

Comment: Is 10 the value in e2 when x>0 or when x==0?

Comment: The best way to understand what's happening is to step through this in a debugger, and examine the variables at each step.

Answer (score 0):

**I have reformatted the code:**

```
class Echo {
    int count = 0;
    void hello() {
        System.out.println("hellooo...");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Echo e1 = new Echo();
        Echo e2 = new Echo();
        int x = 0;
        while (x < 4) {
            e1.hello();
            e1.count++;
            if (x == 3) e2.count++;
            if (x > 0) e2.count = e2.count + e1.count;
            x++;
        }
        System.out.println(e2.count);
    }
}
```

If we look at the while loop:

**1) after first loop (x=0):**

e1.count = 1

e2.count = 0

**2) **x=1****

e1.count = 2

e2.count = 0 + 2 = 2

**3) **x=2****

e1.count = 3

e2.count = 2 + 3 = 5

**4) **x=3****

e1.count = 4

e2.count = 6 (as x=3)

e2.count = 6 + 4 = 10

**Hence your output is :**

```
hellooo...
hellooo...
hellooo...
hellooo...
10
```